# How to return value from a function to use it and respone it in router in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, callback, return-value

I am trying to get result from function getWeather() in Nodejs to respone it to json in one router but I can not get it.

```
var request = require('request');
var publicIp = require('public-ip');

function getCity (userip){ 
  var url = `https://ipinfo.io/${userip}/json`;
  request(url, (err, respone, body)=>{
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var city = data['city'];
    return getLocationKey(city);
  })
}

function getLocationKey(city){
  var url = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?q=${city}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  request(url, (err, respone, body)=>{
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var key = data[0].Key;
    return getWeather(key);
  })
}

function getWeather(key){
  var url =  `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/${key}?apikey=${API_KEY}`;  
  request(url, (err, respone, body)=>{
      var weather = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("weather: " + weather);
      return weather;
  })
}
```

I have got result from getCity() and getLocationKey(), but when get final result from getWeather() is not successfull.
I console.log weather is Object object. I try to sepate it and call it only, it respone for me weatherDetails as [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLgX9.png)

```
router.get('/weather-weather', (req, res)=>{
  var city = 'hanoi';
  var key = '353412'
  var url =  `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/${key}?apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  request(url, (err, respone, body)=>{
    var weatherDetails = JSON.parse(body);
    res.json(weatherDetails);
  })
})
```

However, I want to call it in this route to respone a json but it fail

```
router.get('/weather', (req, res)=>{
  publicIp.v4()
  .then(userip=>{
    console.log("userIP: " + userip); 
    getCity(userip);
  })
  .catch(err=>{ 
    console.log('Error: '+ err);
  })
  })
```

But it failed. I don't know how to return respone result from getWeather() function. How I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function getXXX cannot get the "return" inside the callback function.

And you did not call res.json to send the result to the client.

You could pass res to getXXX and use it in this way:

```
function getCity(userip, res) {
  var url = `https://ipinfo.io/${userip}/json`;
  request(url, (err, respone, body) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var city = data['city'];
    return getLocationKey(city, res);
  })
}

function getLocationKey(city, res) {
  var url = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?q=${city}&apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  request(url, (err, respone, body) => {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var key = data[0].Key;
    return getWeather(key, res);
  })
}

function getWeather(key, res) {
  var url = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/${key}?apikey=${API_KEY}`;
  request(url, (err, respone, body) => {
    var weather = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("weather: " + weather);
    res.json(weather);
  })
}

router.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
  publicIp.v4()
    .then(userip => {
      getCity(userip, res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    })
})
```